# View PHP file, not downloading it

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I was **using localhost** to test my HTML file, but it downloads the PHP file instead of viewing it.
How do you make it VIEW the PHP file, not downloading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a web server to execute the PHP locally.

You can install and run an actual webserver (e.g. nginx or apache) or run the [embedded version of the php server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).